# Bash Sed regex - How to separate IP:PORT without interfering with other NUMBER:NUMBER formats in a line?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to separate the IP and Port on the last part of the line but there are other colons present in the line so I have to use regex to identify the IPv4 format, then isolate the matched pattern to `IP:` then replace the colon with a comma keeping the IP part of the pattern unchanged.
I know I have to use capture groups, but it appears its not doing anything?

Input Data:

```
Aug 4 23:45:23,10.10.3.1,snort[92683]:,[1:2025701:2],ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File,[Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic],[Priority: 2],TCP,10.10.0.2:6342,10.10.3.3:445
```

Expected Output:

```
Aug 4 23:45:23,10.10.3.1,snort[92683]:,[1:2025701:2],ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File,[Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic],[Priority: 2],TCP,10.10.0.2,6342,10.10.3.3,445
```

Current Command:

```
sed -r 's/(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b):/\1,/g;'
```

Comment: Unfortunately dupe answer is all about `\d` only and doesn't cover word boundary in `sed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` traditionally doesn't support perl regex properties such as `\w`, `\d` etc in regex.

You may use this `sed` with a shortened regex:

```
sed -E 's/(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}):/\1,/g' file
```

**A note on word boundaries:**

Note that gnu-sed does support `\b` or `\<` for word boundary, however BSD sed doesn't support it and you may have to use `[[:<:]]` on OSX `sed`.